# dns server set up

Tags: dns, bind

I am trying to install a dns server and after running `sudo named-checkzone ostechnix.lan /etc/bind/for.austen.lan`. I get the error

```
zone austen.lan/IN: 
NS 'pri.austen.lan.austen.lan' has no address records (A or AAAA)
zone austen.lan/IN: NS 'sec.austen.lan.austen.lan' has no address records (A or AAAA)
zone austen.lan/IN: not loaded due to errors.
```

Here is my forward and reverse zone files

```
$TTL 86400
@   IN SOA   pri.austen.lan.  root.austen.lan (
       2011071001  ;Serial
       3600        ;Refresh
       1800        ;Retry
       604800      ;Expire
       86400       ;Minimum TTL
)
@      IN  NS     pri.austen.lan
@      IN  NS     sec.austen.lan
@      IN  A      10.142.0.2
@      IN  A      10.142.0.2
@      IN  A      10.142.0.2
pri    IN  A      10.142.0.2
sec    IN  A      10.142.0.2
client IN  A      10.142.0.2
```

my reverse file is

```
$TTL 86400
@   IN SOA   pr.austen.lan. root.austen.lan. (
       2011071002  ;Serial
       3600        ;Refresh
       1800        ;Retry
       604800      ;Expire
       86400       ;Minimum TT
)
@      IN NS pri.austen.lan.
@      IN NS sec.austen.lan.
@      IN PTR austen.lan.
pri    IN A   10.142.0.2
sec    IN A   10.142.0.2
client IN A   10.142.0.2
200    IN PTR pri.austen.lan
201    IN PTR sec.austen.lan
202    IN PTR cleint.austen.lan.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your forward zone file has missing periods and other syntax errors. Try this (my file name is `db.austen.lan`):

```
$TTL 86400
@   IN SOA   austen.lan.  root.austen.lan. (
       2018111201  ;Serial
       3600        ;Refresh
       1800        ;Retry
       604800      ;Expire
       86400       ;Minimum TTL
)
       IN  A      10.142.0.2
;
@      IN  NS     pri.austen.lan.
pri    IN  A      10.142.0.2
@      IN  NS     sec.austen.lan.
sec    IN  A      10.142.0.2
;
client IN  A      10.142.0.2
```

Which passes the check:

```
doug@DOUG-64:~/config/etc/bind/test4$ named-checkzone austen.lan db.austen.lan
zone austen.lan/IN: loaded serial 2018111201
OK
```

Similarly for your reverse file ( my file name is `db.10`):

```
$TTL 86400
@   IN SOA   pri.austen.lan. root.austen.lan. (
       2018111201  ;Serial
       3600        ;Refresh
       1800        ;Retry
       604800      ;Expire
       86400       ;Minimum TTL
)
@      IN NS pri.austen.lan.
@      IN NS sec.austen.lan.
2      IN PTR pri.austen.lan.
2      IN PTR sec.austen.lan.
2      IN PTR cleint.austen.lan.
```

Which passes the check:

```
doug@DOUG-64:~/config/etc/bind/test4$ named-checkzone 0.142.10.in-addr.arpa db.10
zone 0.142.10.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 2018111201
OK
```

Comment: Thanks that seemed to work however i am now running the command sudo named-checkzone ostechnix.lan /etc/bind/for.ostechnix.lan and getting the errors unknown RR type 'cat'
zone austen.lan/IN: loading from master file /etc/bind/for.austen.lan failed: unknown class/type
zone austen.lan/IN: not loaded due to errors.

Comment: Sounds as though you included the first line of my example code segments, where I included the `cat` line, just so that you would know what file names I used. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I got Dns setup (thanks for the help) however when i run nslookup austen.lan i get ** server can't find austen.lan: NXDOMAIN

Comment: please edit your question and add the contents of `/etc/bind/named.conf.local` and `named.conf.options`. does `nslookup client.austen.lan` work?

Comment: Here is the contents of /etc/bind/named.conf.local the file is blank same with named.conf.options. and nslookup client.austen.lan returns the same error

Comment: Well, no wonder it doesn't work, as you haven't declared the zone. I don't know what you are using as a reference, but I suggest the [Ubuntu Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/dns.html).